# Yield not returning value

Tags: php, yield

I'm trying to adapt this code:

```
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        echo implode($perms); // yield (implode($perms));
    }  else {
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
             list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
         }
    }
}
```

To a yield, as you see commented in the same line. But doing so returns no values.

I'm calling it with:

```
  foreach (pc_permute($a) as $y) {
        echo $y;
  }
```

Where $a should be something like `$a = [0,1,2];`

With echo works and with yield does not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So i'm yielding to a recursive function, which is returning nothing. How would I escalate that to grandparent's function?              ` yield pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);         yield (implode($perms)); `
Something like that returns generator objects ad infinitum

Comment: I did the trick in another part with something like:           array_push($this->permutations, $perms); instead of the yield, but I would like a better way, like directly retrieve the yield

Comment: python has `yield from`, if there's nothing similar, write a loop.

Comment: yield from pc_permute($newitems, $newperms); was it! Thanks a lot. Would you answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive call ignores the yielded values.

Since PHP 7 you can use [generator delegation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) (`yield from`):

```
yield from pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
```

With older versions just write a loop that yields each result.